# pandas select from Dataframe using startswith

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

This works (using Pandas 12 dev)

```
table2=table[table['SUBDIVISION'] =='INVERNESS']
```

Then I realized I needed to select the field using "starts with" Since I was missing a bunch.
So per the Pandas doc as near as I could follow I tried

```
criteria = table['SUBDIVISION'].map(lambda x: x.startswith('INVERNESS'))
table2 = table[criteria]
```

And got AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'startswith'

So I tried an alternate syntax with the same result

```
table[[x.startswith('INVERNESS') for x in table['SUBDIVISION']]]
```

Reference http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing
Section 4: List comprehensions and map method of Series can also be used to produce more complex criteria:

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you give a small example which demonstrates this, I'm surprised that the list comprehension wouldn't raise in the same way as the map...

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can use the [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods) DataFrame method to give more consistent results:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(['a', 'ab', 'c', 11, np.nan])

In [12]: s
Out[12]:
0      a
1     ab
2      c
3     11
4    NaN
dtype: object

In [13]: s.str.startswith('a', na=False)
Out[13]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

and the boolean indexing will work just fine (I prefer to use `loc`, but it works just the same without):

```
In [14]: s.loc[s.str.startswith('a', na=False)]
Out[14]:
0     a
1    ab
dtype: object
```

.

*It looks least one of your elements in the Series/column is a float, which doesn't have a startswith method hence the AttributeError, the list comprehension should raise the same error...*

Comment: Thank you for your reply...Don't seem to be getting there Tried table['SUBDIVISION']str.startswith('INVERNESS', na=False) and got   table['SUBDIVISION']str.startswith('INVERNESS', na=False)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  Wondering if I did not import something essential? I don't get it since my straight == condition works fine

Comment: And if I try  table.loc[table['SUBDIVISION'].str.startswith('INVERNESS', na=False)] I get a good result!! But I still don't get what is wrong with the prior attempts?

Comment: @dartdog you were missing a dot. please include a small subset of the data which demonstrates the problem (it seems hard to believe :s)

Comment: Sorry the data is 27 cols long, kind of unwieldy even to post a clip. I tried this> table['SUBDIVISION'].str.startswith('INVERNESS',na='False') with another '.' and the comparison came out bad (all selected false)  I still don't get why my original syntax failed since I thought I was following the documentation.

Comment: @dartdog presumably it's only the SUBDIVISION column which is relevant, so just paste that.

Comment: 0         MT HIGH
1      LAKE CYRUS
2      TRUSSVILLE
3         CLANTON
4    BEAVER CREEK
Name: SUBDIVISION, dtype: object

Comment: Do you mind just pastebinning SUBDIVISION, I can't read_clipboard that.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/imjNEwg3 see also pasted data above MT HIGH.... the pastebin is the properly selected data. the data above is a sample of the "unselected"

Comment: @dartdog can't replicate, perhaps output of .to_dict() would help

Comment: Asking for more help here https://groups.google.com/d/topic/pydata/_QX9YiPZldw/discussion

Answer (score 34):

To retrieve all the rows which **startwith** required string

```
dataFrameOut = dataFrame[dataFrame['column name'].str.match('string')]
```

To retrieve all the rows which **contains** required string

```
dataFrameOut = dataFrame[dataFrame['column name'].str.contains('string')]
```

Comment: Why use the `str.match()` function to determine whether a value starts with a specific string when you could use `str.startswith()`?  `str.match()` is for matching a value against a regular expression.  If you don't need a regular expression, using that function **_may_** make your code slower than necessary.

Answer (score 16):

Using startswith for a particular column value

```
df  = df.loc[df["SUBDIVISION"].str.startswith('INVERNESS', na=False)]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `apply` to easily apply any string matching function to your column elementwise.

```
table2=table[table['SUBDIVISION'].apply(lambda x: x.startswith('INVERNESS'))]
```

this assuming that your "SUBDIVISION" column is of the correct type (string)

Edit: fixed missing parenthesis

Comment: This worked for me once I added another closing bracket

`table2=table[table['SUBDIVISION'].apply(lambda x: x.startswith('INVERNESS')]]`

Answer (score 3):

This can also be achieved using [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
table.query('SUBDIVISION.str.startswith("INVERNESS").values')
```