# How to check if a serial number starts with 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Im excluding rows from my df that fill certain conditions

```
df[~((df['Wood_type'] == 'pine') & (df['wood_size'] == 20))]
```

I would like to also exclude, the numbers that start with 0 in the column 'Serial'

```
df[~((df['Wood_type'] == 'pine') & (df['wood_size'] == 20) & (df['Serial'] == range(0) == 0))]
```

I tried the above, no result.

Comment: How does a number start with zero? Is it actually a string?

Comment: would be a example: 0123.FX

Comment: Could you explain what do you imagine `df['Serial'] == range(0) ==0` does?

Comment: exclude rows where a value in column Serial, starts with number 0, like 0123.FX

Comment: Can you tell me how? Why are you using a `range` object? Are you aware of the implications of using two `==` in an expression? Finally, which part of that checks the first character in your string?

Comment: im not sure how, thats why i made this post.

Comment: I've noticed that you have not selected any answers to your other questions. You should consider going through, and giving answerers the credit they are due by clicking on the check marks. It helps their reputation and yours, and it's the right thing to do in this forum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas select from Dataframe using startswith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957890/pandas-select-from-dataframe-using-startswith)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use [`df.str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.htmlhttps://) to check the first character:

```
df[ ~((df['Wood_type'] == 'pine') & (df['wood_size'] == 20) & (df['Serial'].str.startswith('0')))]
```

The current expression `df['Serial'] == range(0) == 0` is meaningless. It is equivalent to `df['Serial'] == range(0) and range(0) == 0`. Clearly, neither of those is related to comparing the first character of the string to `'0'` (as opposed to `0`).