# Using Python DataFrame trying to extract all rows for columns starting with a certain number

Tags: python, dataframe, startswith

The code below doesn't work because AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith'.
How do I do get this code to work?

```
#Starts with account num and negative
negExpense = (df.Amount < float(0)) & \
            (df.loc[df['Account'].startswith(5)])
print(negExpense)
debits.to_excel(writer, 'Negative Expense')
```

Comment: do: `df['Account'].str.startswith(5)`

Comment: its [pandas.Series.str.startswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Pandasql to use reg-exp. You can manipulate your dataframe using pandasql library and replacing the earlier df with new_df.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`df.str.startswith(5)`** instead of just startswith.

This link will help you out for further info - [pandas select from Dataframe using startswith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957890/pandas-select-from-dataframe-using-startswith)

Comment: Gives me this: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @ShreddedScientist can you try converting the field to string by str() and the apply .str function?