# same string from all the row python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have some data, the first column is the login, the second column is comment which is string or numbers or both, the data is this:

```
Login Comment
256   qq456
257   msn176453
```

I want to find all the rows that the the begining of the comment is qq. I was trying to use:

```
sentence_begining = r"[qq.]"
re.findall(sentence_begining, orders["Comment"])
```

however,this way failed, after googling a lot, I still cannot solve this problem. So I am wondering others may also have this question, so post it here. Many thanks

Comment: _however,this way failed_ Failed how, in what way? _after googling a lot, I still cannot solve this problem._ Googling "pandas check if string starts with", first result: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas select from Dataframe using startswith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957890/pandas-select-from-dataframe-using-startswith)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
orders[orders['Comment'].str.startswith('qq')]
```